# Grails 2.5.5 error with 'as JSON' on a domain class that has an equals method

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-domain-class

I just came into an error when I tried to get the current logged user from springSecurityService and render it as JSON.

```
def user = springSecurityService.getCurrentUser()
println user as JSON // EXCEPTION!
```

User is a domain class and had an equals method, the error below happens because the 'as JSON' seems to be calling the equals method (I don't understand why).

User looks like this:

```
class User implements Serializable {
   ...
   String username
   String password
   String email
   ...

   @Override
   boolean equals(other)
   {
      is(other) || (other.instanceOf(User) && other.username == username)
   }
   ...
}
```

This is the exception: (the error is on the .instanceOf(User))

```
2016-10-11 05:40:24,706 [http-bio-8090-exec-1] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - MissingMethodException occurred when processing request: [POST] /ehr/query/save

No signature of method: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONObject$Null.instanceOf() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Class) values: [class com.cabolabs.security.User]. Stacktrace follows:

Message: No signature of method: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONObject$Null.instanceOf() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Class) values: [class com.cabolabs.security.User]

    Line | Method
->>   45 | equals    in com.cabolabs.security.User
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|    176 | value     in grails.converters.JSON
|    134 | render .  in     ''
|    250 | save      in com.cabolabs.ehrserver.query.QueryController
|    198 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|     53 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter
|     62 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

Is anyone experimenting the same?
Is this the expected behavior or a bug?

Comment: Try this, `println (user as JSON)`

Comment: Another idea, to pin point the culprit; just `return false` from your `equals()`, and then add properties there, one by one.

Comment: Does the `getCurrentUser` method return null? Does the code work if the user is not null (e.g. if you try giving it a `new User()`)?

Comment: @AdeelAnsari the problem is "as JSON" is calling the equals, but passing an instance as parameter that is not a grails instance, that is why the instanceOf method doesn't exists (here: other.instanceOf(User)), only exists for Grails domain classes http://docs.grails.org/2.5.5/ref/Domain%20Classes/instanceOf.html

Comment: @GregorPetrin getCurrentUser() has the logged in user, so it is not null, also the exception doesn't indicate a null problem, it is a method doesn't exists error. Very weird. If I comment the equals method out, the error disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Try not to give `equals()` implementation by yourself, and use this, [`@EqualsAndHashCode`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/index.html?groovy/transform/EqualsAndHashCode.html), annotation, provided by Groovy instead. See if that works.

Or

Check the `instanceOf()` availability before hand, like this

```
(obj.respondsTo('instanceOf') && obj.instanceOf(User))
```

using [`respondsTo()`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/MetaObjectProtocol.html#respondsTo(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String)) method.